# imagemagick convert -crop warning

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying the following:

```
convert -verbose Originals/100A.png -crop 975x1300+450+550 Originals/100_map.png
```

I get the following output:

```
Originals/100A.png PNG 3196x3600 3196x3600+0+0 8-bit sRGB 382KB 0.150u 0:00.160
Originals/100A.png=>Originals/100_map.png PNG 3196x3600=>975x1300 3196x3600+450+550 8-bit sRGB 179c 41KB 0.090u 0:00.089
convert: profile 'icc': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG `Originals/100_map.png' @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1656.
```

A geometry of `975x1300+218+218` does not give the same warning but `975x1300+219+219` does. I'd love to understand how the interpret and address the warning correctly.